# Want to add either class, or add font-style: italic, to specific items in map()

Tags: javascript, dictionary, dom-manipulation, papaparse

I'm using papaParse to convert a CSV to JSON. What I'm trying to figure out is how to only italicize a data.piece if it has the data.type of "Composition".

My console.log works, but I haven't figured out how to correctly implement the DOM manipulation I want.

````
      function init() {
        Papa.parse(public_spreadsheet_url, {
          download: true,
          header: true,
          complete: showInfo
        })
      }

      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init)


      function showInfo(results) {
        var data = results.data

        let dataTypeComposition = (data.map(data=> {if (data.type == "Composition") {
        console.log(data.piece)
     }})) 

        let allData = (data.map(data => `<div class="past-performances"> <div class="datesAndLocations"> <p class="dates"> ${data.date}</p> <p class="locations"> ${data.location} </p></div> <div class="piecesAndDescripts"> <p class="pieces">${data.piece}</p> <p class="descriptions"> ${data.description} </p></div> <br></div>`))
    

    


      document.getElementById("list-container").innerHTML = allData.join(" ")
      } ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a condition in the return of the map. I added indentation for clarity, and removed some extraneous parens.

```
function init() {
  Papa.parse(public_spreadsheet_url, {
    download: true,
    header: true,
    complete: showInfo
  })
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init)


function showInfo(results) {
  const data = results.data

  const allData = data.map(data =>
    `<div class="past-performances">
      <div class="datesAndLocations">
        <p class="dates">${data.date}</p>
        <p class="locations">${data.location}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="piecesAndDescripts">
        <p class="pieces">
          ${data.type === 'Composition' ? `<i>${data.piece}</i>` : data.piece}
        </p>
        <p class="descriptions">${data.description}</p>
      </div>
      <br>
    </div>
  `)

  document.getElementById("list-container").innerHTML = allData.join(" ")
}
```

Comment: yep! This should do it. If your console.log is working then the hard part is done, you just replace the console.log with the conditions you want as shown above. The code sample ```${data.type === 'Composition' ? `<i>${data.piece}</i>` : data.piece}``` is a bit of shorthand, but it's just another way to write an if statement.